# Linked list segmentation fault for list size

Tags: c

```
struct node {
    int value;
    struct node* next;
};

struct node* alloc_node() {
    return malloc(sizeof(struct node));
}

int get_count(struct node* head) {
    int node_count;
    struct node* iterator;

    node_count = 1;
    iterator = head;
    while (iterator->next != NULL) {
        iterator = iterator->next;
        node_count++;
    }

    return node_count;
}
```

I'm building a Linked List from scratch to get a better understanding of the C language. The program compiles but gives a segmentation fault when run. This started happening after the get_count() method was implemented. Any ideas as to why this is happening? Below is where the method is being called:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "linked_list.c"

int main() {
    // create head
    struct node* head;
    head = alloc_node();

    // create first node
    struct node* link;
    link = alloc_node();
    link->value = 5;

    (*head).next = link;

    int size = get_count(head);
    printf("%d\n", size);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while (iterator->next != NULL)` --> `while (iterator != NULL)`???

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You mind creating a [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Just tried your suggestion and it still gives a seg fault.

Comment: `link->next` is uninitialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct node* alloc_node() {
    return malloc(sizeof(struct node));
}
```

You return an uninitialized node. What guarantee is there that `next` is ever initialized to NULL, for you to later check against in `get_count`?

Initialize it explicitly:

```
struct node* alloc_node() {
    struct node* ret = malloc(sizeof *ret);
    if (ret) { 
      ret->next = NULL;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

---

The rule of thumb when writing APIs for software libraries, is that every assumption you make must be documented or **enforced** by the library itself. Implicit assumptions that a user is unaware of are not a good foundation to program with.